# Adding pages to RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I am a newbie in `rails` and `RefineryCMS` and I want to add a new html page that appears in both `RefineryCMS` interface and in `rails` application folder.
But when I add the page from interface and use this commande to have all the pages

```
 rake refinery:override view=refinery/pages/*
```

I just get the home and show pages.
So how to get this page to modify it from my application or how to create the page from my application folder and get it visible in my `RefineryCMS` inetrface?

Comment: is my question not clear ?

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong, because I`m a newbie too, but:

1. Pages, which are created from the UI of Refinery, are stored in database (check the logs of the web server, when creating them). They are than passed to the home.html.erb and rendered within this template. So you can wrap the data from Refinery in something, but not modify this data here.
2. In order to have an ability to modify the contents fully consider the following variants:
   a. You can add additional sections via Refinery. 
   b. You can create a separate engine for this. 
   Both variants are covered in RailsCasts. The second variant is more complex but more flexible too.